# Wso2 cluster coordination: Database table error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to enable cluster coordination in my aws environment. However I keep getting an error saying ***Couldn't initialize the ESB... org.wso2.micro.integrator.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: DataSource WSO2_TRANSACTION_DB is not configured properly***.
If I remove the transaction database configs from the deployment.toml, there is no error, but the cluster coordination still doesn't work. I've tried deleting and recreating the transactiondb database and tables but it still doesn't work.

I followed this doc [Cluster coordination in wso2](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/databases/setting-up-mysql/)

I create the transactiondb and tables as follows:
create database transactiondb character set latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CURRENT_STATS (
TIME_STAMP DATE NOT NULL,
NODE_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
TRANSACTION_COUNT INT NOT NULL,
TRANSACTION_COUNT_ENCRYPTED VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL
) ENGINE INNODB;

I had initially tried these same configurations to create the tables in my local and it had worked successfully then.

Note: I'm using k8s in aws

Answer (score 0):

The transaction DB is not required for cluster coordination, it's there for billing purposes if you have a WSO2 subscription. So you can simply omit to create this.

For cluster coordination, you need to create the following set of tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LEADER_STATUS_TABLE (
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  NODE_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  LAST_HEARTBEAT BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (GROUP_ID)
)ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CLUSTER_NODE_STATUS_TABLE (
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  NODE_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  IS_NEW_NODE INT NOT NULL,
  LAST_HEARTBEAT BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (GROUP_ID, NODE_ID)
)ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MEMBERSHIP_EVENT_TABLE (
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  NODE_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  CHANGE_TYPE INT NOT NULL,
  CHANGED_MEMBER_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL
)ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REMOVED_MEMBERS_TABLE (
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  NODE_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  REMOVED_MEMBER_ID VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL
)ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COORDINATED_TASK_TABLE (
  TASK_NAME VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
  DESTINED_NODE_ID VARCHAR (512),
  TASK_STATE VARCHAR (32),
  PRIMARY KEY (TASK_NAME)
)ENGINE INNODB;
```

Then provide a unique name to each member in the cluster.

```
[cluster_config]
node_id = "node-1"
```

Take a look at the document [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/deployment/deploying_wso2_ei/#cluster-coordination).

Comment: I am actually already following all the steps you mentioned above. But I still cannot get it to work. The same configurations are working perfectly in my local server, but now when I deploy it. So I was wondering if there are any addition configs to be added when deploying to aws using k8s or something.

Comment: @ahinsa no there aren't any special configurations. Are you properly setting a node_id for each pod? How are you setting them?

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to set the node id in deployment.toml file? Before this I was using the random default UUID that is generated as the node id in my local, so I continued trying the same in my aws deployment..

Comment: @ahinsa yes it is. Each pod should have its unique id which will not change if recreated. If you are using stateful stets. You can use the set Id for this.

Comment: Even after adding the unique name to the cluster it does not work either; no logs displaying successful cluster coordination show up

Comment: The docker image works fine if I try to run it independently too. So i'm really not sure what could be the reason for it going wrong...

Comment: @ahinsa I can't really say anything without seeing more details. Probably try enabling debug logs and see.

Comment: Hey so I figured out the issue was due to the config-map parser we were using when building the docker image; while copying all the files from our repo, we need to skip the ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/conf/.metadata/metadata_config.properties  file. Everything works perfectly then as it autogenerates a new file when running the server image locally. 
HOWEVER, when building the image using the same commands using bitbucket, our build fails as we compulsorily need to add the metadata_config.properties file as it doesn't automatically generate. Was wondering if you had any input?